# Java Program ArrayList: using Collections.shuffle() inside a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, do-while

I am in my first java class.  We are just beginning to work with arrays.  I am given 9 numbers: 45000,30000,150000,200000,175000,250000,195000,225000,300000.   And need to write a java program that breaks down the list into 3 groups of 3 numbers.  The sum of each group must be greater than 500,000.

My first thought was to shuffle the array and test if the sum Index 0,1,2 >500000 ... sum Index 3,4,5 >500000 ... sum Index 6,7,8 >500000?  and loop it until the condition is met.  The idea of "shuffling" the array led me to study ArrayList and the Collections.shuffle() method.

I think I have the ArrayList code correct.  The program compiles.  And my while conditions seem correct, but I am getting output of less than 500000.

Any insight would be appreciated.

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    ArrayList<Integer> productPrices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    productPrices.add(45000);
    productPrices.add(30000);
    productPrices.add(150000);
    productPrices.add(200000);
    productPrices.add(175000);
    productPrices.add(250000);
    productPrices.add(195000);
    productPrices.add(225000);
    productPrices.add(300000);



    List<Integer> prices = Arrays.asList(45000,30000,150000,200000,175000,250000,195000,225000,300000);
    int salesRep2 = 0;
    int salesRep3 = 0;
    int salesRep4 = 0;



    do 
    {   
    Collections.shuffle(prices);

    salesRep2 = prices.get(0) + prices.get(1) + prices.get(2);
    salesRep3 = prices.get(3) + prices.get(4) + prices.get(5);
    salesRep4 = prices.get(6) + prices.get(7) + prices.get(8);


    }while((salesRep2 < 500000) && (salesRep3 < 5000000) && (salesRep4 < 500000));


    System.out.println(salesRep2);
    System.out.println(salesRep3);
    System.out.println(salesRep4);

    }

    }
```

Comment: If you want them all to be at least 500k, you should use `||` rather than `&&` in the condition.

Comment: Is it more than 500K or more than or equal to 500K? You say greater than in the text but not in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `salesRep3 < 5000000` has one 0 to much.

Notes:

- You can use underscores in your number: `salesRep3 < 5_000_000`.
- You can declare the constant in a static constant, so your code can be compiled with other values.

Comment: Worth mentioning that underscores can be used in literals, which makes this kind of error much easier to spot: `5_000_000`

Comment: thank you for the underscore suggestion .. that made my extra zero obvious .. thank you for the || suggestion.   You were correct it was a logic error not a syntax error.

Comment: Now I want to assign a product name to each of the nine numbers in the ArrayList.   For example 45_000 = Paperclips, 30_000 = Staples  ... Eventually, I want to program output 3 products for 3 sales reps so that each rep sales total is greater than 500_000 .. what should I study next so I can add this to my program.